# Convert object of type List<object> to List<string>

Tags: c#, casting

I'm parsing a JSON string using MiniJson in Unity. Now I have a value that's a list of strings. Though I get this an object. The underlying type of the object is a `List<object>`, but actually it should be a `List<string>`. So currently I do this:

```
void SetInfo(Dictionary<string,object> info) {
    Colors = (info["colors"] as List<object>).OfType<string>().ToList();
}
```

The dictionary is what I get from the MiniJson library. This works perfectly. Though seems a bit ugly, a lot of unnecessary casting, and I was wondering if there's a better way of doing this. Mostly I'm looking for cleaner code, and faster execution, since there are a lot of these entries.

Edit: I wasn't very clear about this. In the info dictionary there are a bunch of key/value pairs, the type of the values vary. I can cast most very easily, but the info["colors"] object is the one I'm having problems with.

So when I do `info["colors"]` I get an `object`, with an underlying type `List<object>`. The `objects` in this list are actually `strings`.

Also, there's not really a performance problem here, since it's only called once at the start of the program, though there is a noticeable lag currently, I'm going to put it on it's own thread anyway so no problem there. The faster execution is just out of curiosity.

Comment: did you measure the performance and confirmed that there is a performance problem?

Comment: "The underlying type of the object is a List, but actually it should be a List" you mean dictionary?

Comment: Why is it not sent in as `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`?

Comment: @Weyland, I mean the underlying type of the object I get when I do `info["colors"]`.
@Magnus, there are other values in it aswell. For instance the info["cmc"] is an int.

Comment: I edited my question. I'm only just awake, and my question suffered for it. Should be more clear now I hope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one.

```
(info["colors"] as List<object>).ConvertAll(input => input.ToString());
```

you can also use direct cast `(string)input` or `input as string` which is even faster(there were debates on casting here at stackoverflow).

`info["colors"] as List<object>` can result in null, so I'd rather be more safe and wrap your code like this:

```
List<object> colors = info["colors"] as List<object>;
List<string> typedColors = null;
if (colors!=null)
{
   typedColors = colors.ConvertAll(input => input as string);
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution. Though almost the same. Is there a reason why `ConvertAll` is preferred over my `.OfType<string>().ToList()`; Other than being only one call?

Comment: `OfType` is an extension method and is not a conversion method, it only returns elements that are already of the specified type, and it will be of type IEnumerable<T>. Meanwhile `ConvertAll` is not an extension method - it's native method of List class. You don't have to convert IEnumerable to List and you can convert every element like you need.

Comment: I think you can also use `colors.Cast<string>()` safely if you are sure about all items been of type string.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using the [in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469484.aspx) and [out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx) keywords

Comment: For this problem not, what do you propose?

Comment: Lists(as they are classes) cannot be variant. You can define custom contravariant interface `ICustomList<in T>` to make something like `ICustomList<string> = ICustomList<object>`. But why should you do that, it will cast implicitly anyways.

Comment: ah, I think I have misunderstood how the in and out keywords work then. I have never used them but came across the pages I linked to in my comment and thought they might be helpful. Ah well, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

I know this code is a bit old school, but we all know what it means:

```
    List<object> l = new List<object>();
    List<string> s = new List<string>();
    foreach( var i in l )
        s.Add((string)i);
```